# NodeJS: Can't set headers after they are sent. Error only occurs on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, http-headers

The error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` only appears to happen when my application is deployed on Heroku. It does not occur on a localhost environment.

I managed to narrow down the cause of the problem to this:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null ) {
        res.redirect('http://' + req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + req.url);
        console.log(req.url);
    } else {
        next();
    }

    if(!res.getHeader('Cache-Control')) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' + (86400000*7));
    }
});
```

Could anybody tell me why the code isn't working on Heroku? It appears to crash the application before anyone even visits the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set a header in your middleware but you have already sent the response further in your code.

Just put your `if` near calling `next`:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null ) {
        res.redirect('http://' + req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + req.url);
        console.log(req.url);
    } else {
       if(!res.getHeader('Cache-Control')) {
          res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' + (86400000*7));
       }
        next();
    }  
});
```

Comment: Yeah. That was the issue.